# Best way to store user-to-user chat messages?

Tags: mysql

I'm building a mobile app with user-to-user chat and I decided to use the good old MySQL, instead Firestore. I've installed Ratched library as a PHP socket and I'm good to go.

The only thing that worries me is - how do I store the messages? I was thinking about each conversation to be on a different table named UserA_UserB. Is that the correct way to do it? I think that's better than just 1 table for thousands of messages, since the query would be heavy in the future. Thanks!

Comment: you should use timestamp, fromUser, toUser within a table So you can back trace and regenerate the whole conversation between 2 different users.

Comment: Using your `UserA_UserB` approach seems, at least to me, cumbersome. Imagine 100s of users initiating a chat among themselves and you will have 100x tables created at the backend.

IMO, a single table with archiving old data (ex: last 6 months) is a better approach. That way you don't have to worry about going through millions of records.

Comment: So, `(id, from, to, text, time)` in a single table? But what happens if this table contains 10 million records, wouldn't that be a problem when I try to find the last 10 messages for `UserA`?

Comment: That's where archiving comes into picture. You will need to run a scheduled job that would run each day and archive data (i.e. pull rows from main table and put it in another table) that are "x" days or months old. What you decide the value of "x" to be is up to you.

By doing this, you ensure that your main table records do not run into millions.

Comment: @asprin got it! I'll create a daily cronjob for archiving messages older than 30 days to `messages_archive`, and tweak the PHP - if no more messages were found in `messages`, search in `messages_archive`. BTW, is this the best way to do it? Does Facebook does it like that? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can't say if it's the best way (I'm sure there would be better approaches too), but I do use it in my apps. As for whether anyone else follows it, no idea again :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schematically:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, txt TEXT, another fields);
CREATE TABLE users_to_messages (user_id BIGINT FK users(id),
                                message_id BIGINT FK messages(id),
                                is_author TINYINT CHECK (is_author IN (0,1)));
```

This structure avoids swapping when you need the messages for some separate user, and allows tri-, tetra- and more-alogs.